# Delete more than 1 List item based on Closing date in SPS2013 List

Tags: list, workflow, item, delete, workflow2013

I`ve created a workflow from SPD2013 for SPS2013 List, that will delete the list item based on closing date equals to today. 
Issue, it does it for the only one item, even though if there are more than 1 item with closing date set to today.
I understand workflow suggest for incase of multiple items, it will do it for the first.
Please suggest if any option to perform delete option for multiple items at once?

Comment: @ahmed can you please assist?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up retention policy to start a workflow when any condition (in your case closing data is today) is satisfied. In that workflow you can set step to delete the item. This way multiple items can trigger workflow to do the required functionality.

Comment: thanks but if I want to in future to perform delete and archive, I guess would be an issue?

Comment: You are asking about the archiving the item ? In workflow you can do anything as per your functionality.

Comment: I understand in workflow u can do anything, but not sure how can I achieve to have all items copied and later deleted if the closing date is of Today?

Comment: copy where ??? Another list ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, created a workflow and set it run on all items every night to do the following. **Check workflow Screenshot -**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKowj.jpg

In order to run daily on all items and not just current item (usually workflow will run on one item at a time) -

**Powershell `Code`**

```
    `# URL of the Site 
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "example.com"

$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager 

# Name of the list 
$list = $web.Lists["List name"] 

# Name of the Workflow 
$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Workflow name","en-US") 

$data = $assoc.AssociationData 
$items = $list.Items 
foreach($item in $items) 
 { 
 $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true) 
 } 

$manager.Dispose() 
$web.Dispose()
```